# Rails custom error Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I'm really wondering if there is any way, how to create custom Logging with instant sync for any error on Rails..

So it should be same as `production.log` but just for error messages.
And for example then I can use: `tail -f log/error-prod.log`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could capture errors within the ApplicationController with [rescue_from](http://www.rubytutorial.io/rails-rescue_from/) and then write the error to a log before re-raising the error.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :log_error

  private

  def log_error(e)
    error_log.info(e.message)
    raise(e)
  end

  def error_log
    @error_log ||= Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "error-#{Rails.env.to_s}.log"))
  end
end
```

Comment: U missing there `)` at the end of `@error_log` and then i'm still getting this error `undefined local variable or method "log_error" for ApplicationController:Class Did you mean? logger`

Comment: Sorry fixed: `with: :log_error` not `with: log_error`.

Comment: Yeah i just writing that there is missing `:` but looks nice, going to try raise an error

Comment: now getting `undefined method `join' for Rails:Module`

Comment: fixed, by the way you could also use `ActiveSupport::Logger` instead of plain `Logger`. I believe it just adds different formatting: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/HEAD/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger.rb